# Using functions and group by commands in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

List by warehouse the count of the number of items that have an on hand amount less than 20 items.  Only display those warehouses that have more than one item that is less than 20 on hand.

premier_products;

```
 Select count(on_hand) as items
 from part
 where on_hand < 20
 group by warehouse;
```

im confused with how to incorporate the more than one item into the query

the database is below

```
CREATE DATABASE premier_products;
```

## -- Creating Tables

```
USE premier_products;
```

## -- Rep Table

```
CREATE TABLE rep
(

rep_num char(2) primary key,

last_name varchar(15),

first_name varchar(15),

street varchar(15),

city varchar(15),

state char(2),

zip char(5),

commission decimal(7,2),

rate decimal(3,2) 

);
```

## -- Customer table

```
CREATE TABLE customer

(

customer_num char(3) primary key, 

customer_name varchar(30),

street varchar(15),

city varchar(15),

state char(15),

zip char(5),

balance decimal(7,2),

credit_limit decimal(7,2),

rep_num char(2)

);
```

## -- Orders table

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(

order_num char(5) primary key,

order_date timestamp,

customer_num char(3)

);
```

## -- Order_line table

```
CREATE TABLE order_line

(

order_num char(5),

part_num char(4),

num_ordered int(5),

quoted_price decimal(7,2),

PRIMARY KEY (order_num, part_num)

);
```

## -- Part table

```
CREATE TABLE part

(

part_num char(4) primary key,

description varchar(20),

on_hand int(4),

class char(2),

warehouse char(2),

price decimal (7,2)
);
```

## -- Populate rep table

```
INSERT INTO rep values ('20', 'Kaiser', 'Valerie', '624 Randall', 'Grove', 'FL', '33321', 20542.50, 0.05);
INSERT INTO rep values ('35', 'Hull', 'Richard', '532 Jackson', 'Sheldon', 'FL', '33553', 39216.00, 0.07);
INSERT INTO rep values ('65', 'Perez', 'Juan', '1626 Taylor', 'Fillmore', 'FL', '33336', 23487.00, 0.05);
```

## -- Populate customer table

```
INSERT INTO customer values ('148', 'Al''s Appliance and Sport', '2837 Greenway', 'Fillmore', 'FL', '33336',
6550.00, 7500.00, '20');
INSERT INTO customer values ('282', 'Brookings Direct', '3827 Devon', 'Grove', 'FL', '33321', 431.50, 10000.00, '35');
INSERT INTO customer values ('356', 'Ferguson''s', '382 Wildwood', 'Northfield', 'FL', '33146', 5785.00, 7500.00,
'65');
INSERT INTO customer values ('408', 'The Everything Shop', '1828 Raven', 'Crystal', 'FL', '33503', 5285.25, 5000.00, '35');
INSERT INTO customer values ('462', 'Bargains Galore', '3829 Central', 'Grove', 'FL', '33321', 3412.00, 10000.00, '65');
INSERT INTO customer values ('524', 'Kline''s', '838 Ridgeland', 'Fillmore', 'FL', '33336', 12762.00, 15000.00, '20');
INSERT INTO customer values ('608', 'Johnson''s Department Store', '372 Oxford', 'Sheldon', 'FL', '33553', 2106.00, 10000.00, '65');
INSERT INTO customer values ('687', 'Lee''s Sport and Appliance', '282 Evergreen', 'Altonville', 'FL', '32543', 2851.00, 5000.00, '35');
INSERT INTO customer values ('725', 'Deerfield''s Four Seasons', '282 Columbia', 'Sheldon', 'FL', '33553', 248.00, 7500.00, '35');
INSERT INTO customer values ('842', 'All Season', '28 Lakeview', 'Grove', 'FL', '33321', 8221.00, 7500.00, '20');
```

## -- Populate orders table

```
INSERT INTO orders value ('21608', '2015-10-20', '148');
INSERT INTO orders value ('21610', '2015-10-20', '356');
INSERT INTO orders value ('21613', '2015-10-21', '408');
INSERT INTO orders value ('21614', '2015-10-21', '282');
INSERT INTO orders value ('21617', '2015-10-23', '608');
INSERT INTO orders value ('21619', '2015-10-23', '148');
INSERT INTO orders value ('21623', '2015-10-23', '608');
```

## -- Populate order_line table

```
INSERT INTO order_line value ('21608', 'AT94', 11, 21.95);
INSERT INTO order_line value ('21610', 'DR93', 1, 495.00);
INSERT INTO order_line value ('21610', 'DW11', 1, 399.99);
INSERT INTO order_line value ('21613', 'KL62', 4, 329.95);
INSERT INTO order_line value ('21614', 'KT03', 2, 595.00);
INSERT INTO order_line value ('21617', 'BV06', 2, 794.95);
INSERT INTO order_line value ('21617', 'CD52', 4, 150.00);
INSERT INTO order_line value ('21619', 'DR93', 1, 495.00);
INSERT INTO order_line value ('21623', 'KV29', 2, 1290.00);
```

## --Populate part table

```
INSERT INTO part value ('AT94', 'Iron', 50, 'HW', '3', 24.95);
INSERT INTO part value ('BV06', 'Home Gym', 45, 'SG', '2', 794.95);
INSERT INTO part value ('CD52', 'Microwave Oven', 32, 'AP', '1', 165.00);
INSERT INTO part value ('DL71', 'Cordless Drill', 21, 'HW', '3', 129.95);
INSERT INTO part value ('DR93', 'Gas Range', 8, 'AP', '2', 495.00);
INSERT INTO part value ('DW11', 'Washer', 12, 'AP', '3', 399.99);
INSERT INTO part value ('FD21', 'Stand Mixer', 22, 'HW', '3', 159.95);
INSERT INTO part value ('KL62', 'Dryer', 12, 'AP', '1', 349.95);
INSERT INTO part value ('KT03', 'Dishwasher', 8, 'AP', '3', 595.00);
INSERT INTO part value ('KV29', 'Treadmill', 9, 'SG', '2', 1390.00);
```

Comment: Please format the question before it publish. No need unwanted queries. I think you need to use `HAVING` keyword for solution.

Comment: How would i add that here

Comment: k but having is not what i need and so thatd didnt help at all

Comment: so nice work,your comment didnt help at all

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
HAVING (items > 0)
```

at the end of your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(on_hand) AS items
 FROM part
 WHERE (on_hand < 20)
 GROUP BY warehouse
 HAVING (items > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Display warehouses** that have more than one item that is less than 20 on hand

So you need to include warehouse in the select clause, and the group by clause will form one row for each warehouse value.

```
SELECT warehouse, COUNT(on_hand) AS num_low_stocked_parts
FROM part
WHERE on_hand < 20
GROUP BY warehouse
HAVING COUNT(on_hand) > 0
```

*The having clause allows you to filter on aggregated values.*